# Flutter List null safety The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled

Tags: flutter

I try to make flutter null safety migration, I have this code working before and now I have this error on `List(10)`

```
The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled. Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'
```

Here is my code

```
 List<CardModel> createCards() {
        List<String> asset = [];
        List(10).forEach((f) => asset.add('0${(asset.length + 1)}.png'));
        List(10).forEach((f) => asset.add('0${(asset.length - 10 + 1)}.png'));
        return List(20).map((f) {
          int index = Random().nextInt(1000) % asset.length;
          String _image =
              'assets/' + asset[index].substring(asset[index].length - 6);
          asset.removeAt(index);
          return CardModel(
              id: 20 - asset.length - 1, image: _image, key: UniqueKey());
        }).toList();
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 List<CardModel> createCards() {
        List<String> asset = [];
        List.filled(10, null).forEach((f) => asset.add('0${(asset.length + 1)}.png'));
        List.filled(10, null).forEach((f) => asset.add('0${(asset.length - 10 + 1)}.png'));
        return List.filled(10, null).map((f) {
          int index = Random().nextInt(1000) % asset.length;
          String _image =
              'assets/' + asset[index].substring(asset[index].length - 6);
          asset.removeAt(index);
          return CardModel(
              id: 20 - asset.length - 1, image: _image, key: UniqueKey());
        }).cast<CardModel>().toList();
      }
```

Note that when you ommit the type param `List(...)` the default is `dynamic`, so: `List<dynamic>()` equals to `List()`

If `List(N)` create a list of type `dynamic` of size `N` with all values equals to `null`, then after null-safety you can replicate this by using `List.filled(10, null)`.

And use `cast<T>()` to convert the list type to be able to use it as return value which expects the type `CardModel`.